# The D- OnePiece

Tags: one-piece

What is so important about the characters with the middle initial of D? It seems like they're the center of attention in One Piece and the middle initial of D seems to be of some significance. I don't want to actually know what the D stands for, just why people with the initial is important. And everybody should know that the meaning of something and how it is significant is two different things. Duh.

Comment: I don't want to actually know what the D stands for, just why people with the initial is important and what does it mean if you have it. Like are you special, or is it a bad thing to have it.

Comment: I read "Is this an indication of something, or do they really all just have middle initials of the letter D? If they are initials, do we know what they stand for?" as referring to whether or not the initial has any significance, although perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: The significance and meaning behind the D are one and the same.

Comment: How so? The meaning of something and how it is significant is two different things. And i don't need some vague explanation like "They all cause trouble for the Government" Damn near 95% of the characters do that.

Comment: Instead of arguing technicalities, please clarify what exactly it is you want. What significance does the D initial hold and what does the D initial mean are addressed in the dupe question link even if the question doesn't explicitly as for it. If that doesn't answer your question, please explain to us why it does not and what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

People with the D are often very influential.

Influential people we know off:

- Gol D. Roger (Pirate King)
- Portgas D. Ace (First Mate of Whitebeard Pirates)
- Marshal D. Teach (Former Pirate, Pirate Hunter, Shichibukai)
- Monkey D. Dragon (Leader of the rebels)
- Monkey D. Garp (Vice Admiral of the Marines)
- Monkey D. Luffy (Pirate, defeated multiple Shichibukai, broke into Enie's Lobby, broke out of Enie's Lobby, defeated CP9)
- Trafalgar D. Water Law (Pirate, former member of the Quichotte family)
- Portgas D. Rouge (mother of Portgas D. Ace, little is known)
- Jaguar D. Saul (former Vice Admiral, helped saving Nico Robin)

So, many people the government hears of, that contain the D, often cause trouble for it.

Like starting a fight between the government and the pirates.

Or letting hundreds of criminal organize themselves.

Or starting an all out war against the government.

And so on.